# POWER BI - Dynamic Line Chart to display customer and associated peers

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-custom-visuals, row-level-security

Is it possible to create a line chart that shows a customer (lets say rank 32nd) compared against other customers with a similar rank (customer rank 30, customer rank 32, customer rank 34 etc.)

This needs to be dynamic using the customer slicer so I can chose any customer at any given time and it will show their relative peers/competition.

To o one step further, is this possible with Row Level Security applied? So if a customer had access to view this dashboard, is it possible to show similar peer performance or will all information about peers be removed by RLS?

Rank is fine and easy to calculate.

However I have over 100 customers which makes the line chart cluttered. so I only want to show a select few customers to make the line chart readable.